# How do I use elasticsearch wikipedia river?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

This might be a silly question, but I cannot find any information about this. I found the github but after I use the command nothing happened.

So, after I installed the plugin, it worked fine, I used this command to create index.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/my_river/_meta -d '
{
    "type" : "wikipedia",
    "wikipedia" : {
        "url" : "http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"
    },
    "index" : {
        "name" : "my_index",
        "type" : "my_type",
        "bulk_size" : 100
    }
}
'
```

I got this back.

```
{"ok":true,"_index":"_river","_type":"my_river","_id":"_meta","_version":3}
```

which also worked fine. But it didn't do anything apart from that. I'm expecting the plugin to download and index the document and make it searchable. It seems like I have to do some other command but I cannot find it anywhere. I'm new to elasticsearch by the way. Please help.

Edit: Log

```
[2013-03-26 20:17:14,864][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Captain Universe] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2013-03-26 20:18:48,860][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Captain Universe] [_river] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], shards [1]/[1], mappings []
[2013-03-26 20:18:49,266][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Captain Universe] [_river] update_mapping [wikipedia] (dynamic)
[2013-03-26 20:18:49,293][INFO ][river.wikipedia          ] [Captain Universe] [wikipedia][wikipedia] creating wikipedia stream river for [http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2]
[2013-03-26 20:18:49,294][INFO ][river.wikipedia          ] [Captain Universe] [wikipedia][wikipedia] starting twitter stream
[2013-03-26 20:18:49,329][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Captain Universe] [wikipedia] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2013-03-26 20:18:49,632][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Captain Universe] [_river] update_mapping [wikipedia] (dynamic)
[2013-03-26 20:18:54,871][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Captain Universe] [wikipedia] update_mapping [page] (dynamic)
```

Comment: How are you searching after that command?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I figured the command wasn't finished, because it was too fast.

Comment: so, try to run curl 'localhost:9200/_count?q=*&pretty'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from `"_version":3` you updated the _meta document several times. Unfortunately, some rivers don't pickup changes in meta doc unless you recreate the type.

Try deleting the river (type in the _river index) using

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_river/my_river
```

command and creating the _meta document again. This will create type my_river again, which will trigger creation of river with new parameters. This problem occurred you initially created the river with wrong parameters and your correct parameter have no effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you mean after I deleted the index I run the command above again?

Comment: No, not index, just type. First you run `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_river/my_river` that will delete type `my_river` in the index `_river` and then you run `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/my_river/_meta -d '{...}'` as you posted in your question. This will create type `my_river` again, which will trigger creation of river with new parameters. This problem occurred you initially created the river with wrong parameters and your correct parameter have no effect.

Comment: Sorry but it's still not doing anything after I deleted that and use this command curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/wikipedia/_meta -d '
{
    "type" : "wikipedia"
}
'{"ok":true,"_index":"_river","_type":"wikipedia","_id":"_meta","_version":1}

Comment: Check the log file and see if you have anything in the my,_river index

Comment: I think I found the problem I try to get status and I got {"_index":"_river","_type":"wikipedia","_id":"_status","_version":1,"exists":true, "_source" : {"error":"NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class with value [wikipedia]]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[wikipedia]; ","node":{"id":"bFnwNasZQ0msvTgmmoAhuQ","name":"Eleggua","transport_address":"inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]"}}}

Comment: Did you restart elasticsearch after installing the plugin? Did you check the logs to make sure that the plugin was successfully loaded?

Comment: Thanks, I have reinstalled and restarted and it kinda worked from the log. Could you also give me one more example of how to search through wikipedia?

Comment: `curl "localhost:9200/my_river/my_type/_search?q=test"`